# How to change event height in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar

I want to change the event height in Fullcalendar. These events are from my google calendar. I want the events in fullcanlendar to appear with no space in between.
I dont know if it is a css or js issue.

[image]

Comment: Please post some code and a jsfiddle,so people can understand your problem and provide useful feedback

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open your fullcalendar.css or (...min.css), search the class `.fc-event` and add this line to your class:

```
height:60px !important;
```

Comment: This is not better anser, we looking for how to change this by customizing from properties calendar

Answer (score 0):

Set `eventRender` callbacks and change the CSS style like this:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    element.css("font-size", "1.2em");
    element.css("padding", "5px");
}
```

[Documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to work with the agendaEventMinHeight option: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/agendaEventMinHeight